# How to split input file into words in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist, split

I have to read text from an input file in Java, and first split it into lines and then words. This method used here, to my understanding is to store the words in a list. Can you explain me a bit more how this method works or how can I do it differently? Thank you!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StoreLinesFormat {
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> storeDataList;

    public StoreLinesFormat() {

    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> readFormat(ArrayList<String> inputDataList) {
        ArrayList<String> data = inputDataList;
        if (data != null) {
            storeDataList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

            for (String string : data) {
                ArrayList<String> inner = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(string.split(" ")));
                storeDataList.add(inner);
            }

            return storeDataList;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Array error detected. NULL array value.");
            return null;
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. What's not clear in that piece of code? What are you having a problem grasping?

Comment: Hey and thank you for answering. Well I don't truly understand what happens line by line as I don't have a deep knowledge of Java and I'm trying to read about each method separately but I don;t understand the use of all of them together.

Comment: Ask for more precise questions, for example give us the first line you don't understand. You'll have much more success here when asking precise questions (that Google isn't able to answer directly). And remember that Java provides documentation for its classes !

Comment: This is the part I dont truly understand what is happening.                                
     public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> readFormat(ArrayList<String> inputDataList) {
        ArrayList<String> data = inputDataList;
        if (data != null) {
            storeDataList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

Comment: It's just the declaration of a new method called `readFormat()`, that needs an `ArrayList` of `String` as input, and that returns an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` of `String`.

Comment: I dont understand what an array list of an array list is. Which one is the line and which one is the word

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me break it down for you.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> readFormat(ArrayList<String> inputDataList)
```

This method takes an ArrayList as an argument, the ArrayList used to have a line stored of the file on its every index.

e.g 1st Line of file = arrayList(1st index)
    2nd Line of file = arrayList(2st index)

So coming down,

```
for (String string : data) {
                ArrayList<String> inner = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(string.split(" ")));
                storeDataList.add(inner);
            }
```

This foreach loops iterate each index and then separates each word with a blank space and creates a new list to store these separated words.

The result is an arrayList having a separate ArrayList on its every index, which have separated words on its every index.

**For an alternative - neat solution**

In case its too complex for you to handle, take a look at this solution

https://www.javacodex.com/Files/Read-File-Word-By-Word

Answer (score 0):

`inputDataList` seems to be an `ArrayList` containing the file line by line.

Then `inner` gets, for every cycle of that `for` loop, each word (where "word" means the line separated at the space character, in this case), because `split` has been called on the single line you're analyzing inside that loop.

At that point the separated words are added en masse to `storeDataList`, and the cycle repeats for each element of the array (i.e. each line of the file).